# How to initialize viewmodel in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Suppose I have following model and an `Index` action method.

```
public class detailsbyclientIdviewModel
{
    public int upldId { get; set; }
    public IPagedList<detailsbyClientId> detailsbyclientId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Metadata> metadata { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Ids { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Records> records { get; set; }
}
```

I have an action method as below.

```
public ActionResult Index(detailsbyclientIdviewModel model)
{
    documentVerificationBAL objBAL = new documentVerificationBAL();
    string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
    List<Records> documentstobeVerified = objBAL.getverificationRecords();
    //Assigning recieved data to Model
    model = new detailsbyclientIdviewModel()
    {
        records = documentstobeVerified,
        detailsbyclientId=new IPagedList<detailsbyclientId>()
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

I have many action methods and retrieving data in view. I have detailsbyclientId.someproperties in my view. When the first time page runs I am getting error like object is not initialised(definitly holding `null` value).  So how can I initialise all those properties?

Comment: Is there any reason that your `Index` action requires `detailsbyclientIdviewModel model` as a parameter?

Comment: No..............but i want to return records to the view

Comment: can you please share your `View/.cshtml` page code ?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole If there is no reason, then remove that parameter. You can initialize properties as you already did in the action method, or in the cosntructor of `detailsbyclientIdviewModel`

Comment: May i know how can i make use of constructors?

Comment: If for example `Ids` is the property which is throwing the nullref exception, you can just assign the empty list to it before passing it to the view. Or you can assign it right at the place of declaration: `public IEnumerable<int> Ids { get; set; } = new List<int>()` (this requires C# 6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you must use model as input in Action in order to return it as input to View. Try:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        documentVerificationBAL objBAL = new documentVerificationBAL();
        string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
        List<Records> documentstobeVerified = objBAL.getverificationRecords();
        //Assigning recieved data to Model
        detailsbyclientIdviewModel  model = new detailsbyclientIdviewModel()
        {
            records = documentstobeVerified,
            detailsbyclientId=new IPagedList<detailsbyclientId>()
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```